# How to send the data from server to device in traccar?

Tags: traccar

Traccar is Modern GPS Tracking Platform and Open Source.
https://www.traccar.org/source-code/

I send the data into device by SMS for Device has IMEI.
I want to know how to send the data from server to device in other way

Answer (score 0):

There is a button in the web app that allows you to send commands from the server to the device. Note that to send a command via a network connection, you need the device to be online.

[image]